# Java Cache Simulation with LRU Gives an Inaccurate Hit Rate

Tags: java, caching, lru

I'm writing a Java program that simulates a variety of cache designs. My design breaks up a Cache into two classes, Cache and Set, with the blocks of a set represented as a Queue so that I can use the LRU algorithm for replacement. Here is my Cache class

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Class to simulate a cache with a specified associativity and number of sets
 * 
 * @author Nick Gilbert
 */
public class Cache 
{
    private Set[] sets;
    private int setAssoc, hitCount, missCount, totalCount;
    private double hitRate, missRate;

    public Cache(int passedNumSets, int passedSetAssoc)
    {
        this.sets = new Set[passedNumSets];
        for(int i = 0; i < this.sets.length; i++)
        {
            this.sets[i] = new Set(passedSetAssoc);
        }
        this.setAssoc = passedSetAssoc;
        this.hitCount = 0; this.missCount = 0; this.totalCount = 0;
        this.hitRate = 0.0; this.missRate = 0.0;
    }

    /**
     * Takes a .dat file name, reads memory addresses from it, and simulates filling the cache
     * as it reads each address
     */
    public void fillFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        while(inFile.hasNextInt())
        {
            totalCount++;
            int addressToRead = inFile.nextInt(); //Getting next byte address
            addressToRead /= 4; //Converting to a word address
            int blockAddress = addressToRead / 4;
            int location = (blockAddress % sets.length); //Location = (MemoryAddress % CacheSize)
            //System.out.println(blockAddress + ": set " + location);
            Set setToPlaceAddress = sets[location];
            boolean isHit = setToPlaceAddress.checkQueue(blockAddress);
            System.out.println(totalCount + "@" + location + ": " + sets[location]);
            if(isHit) {
                hitCount++;
            }
            else {
                missCount++;
            }
            System.out.println(isHit);
        }
        inFile.close();
        hitRate = hitCount / (double)totalCount * 100;
        missRate = missCount / (double)totalCount * 100;
    }

    public int getSetAssoc() {
        return setAssoc;
    }

    public void printStats() {
        System.out.println("Cache Stats!\n-----------------");
        System.out.println(this);
        System.out.println("Hit Count: " + hitCount);
        System.out.println("Miss Count: " + missCount);
        System.out.println("Hit Rate: " + hitRate);
        System.out.println("Miss Rate: " + missRate);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Cache Sets: " + sets.length + "\n");
        sb.append("Set Associativity: " + setAssoc + "\n");
        sb.append("Block Size: 4");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my set class

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 * Class to simulate a set in a cache
 * @author Nick Gilbert
 */
public class Set {
    private Queue<Integer> blocks; //Data contained in the set
    private int setLength; //Set associativity

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Set(int setLength)
    {
        this.setLength = setLength;
        blocks = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    }

    /**
     * Check if the block is already there and placing it if it is not
     */
    public boolean checkQueue(int blockAddress) {
        if(blocks.contains(blockAddress)) { //If the queue contains the address
            updateQueue(blockAddress); //Move it to the back (most recently used)
            //System.out.println(blockAddress + ": hit");
            return true; //It's a hit
        }
        insertWithLRU(blockAddress); //Insert address with LRU algorithm
        //System.out.println(blockAddress + ": miss");
        return false; //It's a miss
    }

    /**
     * Method to move address to the back of the queue
     */
    private void updateQueue(int mostRecent) {
        Iterator<Integer> queueIterator = blocks.iterator(); //Iterator to check through the queue
        while(queueIterator.hasNext()) { //Finding the matching address
            int addressToCheck = queueIterator.next(); 
            if(addressToCheck == mostRecent) { //When we've found it
                queueIterator.remove();  //Remove it to be readded
                break;
            }
        }
        blocks.add(mostRecent); //Re-adding it to the back
    }

    /**
     * Algorithm to remove the least recently used address and add a new one
     */
    private void insertWithLRU(int address) {
        if(blocks.size() >= setLength) { //If queue is full
            blocks.remove();
            //System.out.println(blocks.remove() + " removed"); //Remove the front one, the least recently used
        }
        blocks.add(address); //Add new one to the back
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = "[";
        Iterator<Integer> queueIterator = blocks.iterator(); //Iterator to check through the queue
        while(queueIterator.hasNext()) { //Finding the matching address
            str += queueIterator.next() + ", ";
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

And my main class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * A program to simulate different types of caches for statistical analysis
 * on how different cache setups compare to each other
 * 
 * Nick Gilbert
 * 
 * NOTES: Using Byte Addresses
 * Take address from file, convert to a word address
 * 4 words per block
 * block size = 4
 * byte / 4 = word
 * word / 4 = block
 * block % rowsInCache = location
 * 
 * Rows = numSets
 * Cols = setAssoc
 */
//TODO FIX LRU ALGORITHM
public class CacheSimulator 
{
    /**
     * Main method
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //Creating the cache
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numSets, setAssoc;

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter number of cache sets (1/32/64/128/256/512): ");
            numSets = in.nextInt();
        }
        while(numSets != 1 && numSets != 32 && numSets != 64 && numSets != 128 && numSets != 256 && numSets != 512);

        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter set associativity (1/2/4): ");
            setAssoc = in.nextInt();
        }
        while(setAssoc != 1 && setAssoc != 2 && setAssoc != 4);

        Cache cache = new Cache(numSets, setAssoc);
        System.out.println("Cache created!");

        //Getting file to read from
        System.out.print("Enter the filename to check: ");
        String datFile = in.next();

        //Filling cache from file
        in.close(); //End of keyboard input
        cache.fillFromFile(datFile);
        cache.printStats();
    }
}
```

It seems to work on small files. I read in byte addresses from .dat files and map them to the cache. However when I run it on [this .dat file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=79726B8C71E892CD!35541&authkey=!ADr97P9cNKjoT_s&ithint=file%2Cdat) it is supposed to give a miss count of 211414. Instead it says the miss count is 183099 which is far fewer than what is supposed to be. I've tried debugging with small files and it appears to work fine but I can't get it to work with this file.

NOTE: This program does work with 1-way/direct-mapped Cache so the problem seems to be with the LRU algorithm but I don't know what.

Comment: Consider using `LinkedHashMap` in LRU mode for performance, simpler code, and a validated algorithm. If direct-mapped works then it sounds like an associativity mapping bug. (fyi, I have an [immature](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/) tracing/simulator package)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! Turns out it has nothing to do with LRU. When a cache's set associativity increases it does not increase the number of available slots in the Cache. Therefore

```
this.sets = new Set[passedNumSets];
```

Should be

```
this.sets = new Set[passedNumSets / setAssoc];
```